# como puedo poner un combobox, sobre un texbox al seleccionar un button en C# y MySQL

Tags: c#, combobox

espero que se encuentren bien. mi duda es algo sencillo pero la verdad no poseo el conocimiento básico.

la idea es la siguiente tengo un botón en c# que dice buscar y deseo que al momento que le de click al boton en automatico me quite el texbox asignado a nombre del producto y lo cambie por un combobox. alguien tendra idea de como se puede hacer si es asi muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien que es lo quieres hacer con ello pero puedes intentar algo con la propiedad visible, superpones el textBox y el comboBox uno encima del otro en el editor gráfico, y la propiedad visible del comboBox la dejas en false y luego desde el evento click del boton cambias estas propiedades:

```
 private void buttonChangeVisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           button1.Visible = false;
           comboBox1.Visible = true;

     }
```